# Distributed 3 Dimension Arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, distributed-computing, distributed

I'm trying to distribute this Array into 2 processes each should have 5 lines I mean from `zeros(10,10,10)` each should have `zeros(5,5,10)` can someone help? I need it to be distributed in Rows and not in Colon, please

```
y=zeros(10,10,10)
distribute(y; dist=(2,1,100))
 

Im getting this error ==>error BoundsError: attempt to access 2-element Array{Int64,1} at index [1:200]
```